# Inmon data Marts vs Kimball data marts

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, datamart

Is the only difference between kimball and inmon, the Enterprise layer(EDW). I was googling around and found out that inmon also creates data marts using EDW. so does that mean, both these data marts are similar in structure for a given business process and source systems ?

Once the data marts are readily available for both the procedures, do they give same performance ?

correct me if i am wrong, the data warehouse is created first and then dimensional model is created on top of it for specific business requirements.(ER model to Dimensional model)

I was not able find information on how data marts are created in inmon model.I hope some of you could help me in this.

Comment: google `inmon vs kimball`  first link - http://searchbusinessintelligence.techtarget.in/tip/Inmon-vs-Kimball-Which-approach-is-suitable-for-your-data-warehouse
and so on....

In two words - kimball - good for business users pain for IT, Inmon - good for IT - pain for business

Comment: Yeah I am aware of this basic difference. But I was looking for how data marts are created in Inmon's procedure ? As per my research, both are using dimensional modelling. But if its the case both should give approximately equal performance. But its not.

Answer (score -1):

Kimball = create all data marts and after with these we create a DW = Agile methodology = used if I don't have all informations at the beginning

Inmon = Create a DW and after we can create data marts = V Model  = Used if I have global informations in the beginning