# De-normalizing SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas, olap

Table layout:

.Net application is capturing the data in 4 tables

- `A1` (which has FK's to other 3 lookup tables)
- `LK_C1` (fk to A1 and LK_R1, LK_R2 and A1)
- `LK_R1` (fk to LK_C1 and LK_R2 and A1)
- `LK_R2` (fk to LK_C1 and LK_R1 and A1)

Now there are some cases where `LK_C1` and `LK_R2` have relationships skipping `LK_R1`.

Making this into OLAP tables.

I got it that `A1` is going to turn into a fact table with various keys plus any other common dimension keys I may need.

1. But designing the Lookup Tables (3 LK's above). Should I create that into 1 dimension table?

or

2. Should I break it into 2 dimension tables

   a) Where there is a direct relationship between LK_C1 and LK_R2

   b) where all 3 LK's are inter-related.

In approach 2 I will have 2 additional composite key references in A1 fact table
one for combination of LK_C1 + LK_R2 say in column_7 and LK_C1 + LK_R1 + LKR2 in column_8.

What would be the correct approach to making this into a star schema?

Comment: Consider reading the post mentioned in next SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485432/inmon-data-marts-vs-kimball-data-marts . Then I would advice to check dimenship relationships: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166560.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solution accepted by architect was to put all combinations of 3 look ups making a hiearchy into 1 dimension table.
Taking the identity key from this new dimension table and putting it in Fact table.
Implemented using Merge statement.
Since this was a simple .Net table dump for fast query from SSRS; aggregation was needed. Solution was suppose to be a simple one.
Thanks for all the help and input.